# Hikari CP maxLifetime / idleTimeout

Tags: hikaricp

Hikari CP Version : 2.7.4

This is actually not an issue but some doubts.

a) maxLifetime : retires the connection after 30 mins. Will it also create a new connection automatically at the time of killing it or it waits for a new request and then creates a new connectios? considering pool has more than minIdle.

b) idleTimeout : it will drop after 10 mins of inactivity? but 10mins is too high. is it ok if i mark it as 10s(10 is min as seen from code) as otherwise there will always be connections higher than min-connections?

ALso when does the connetion is mark as idle?

Answer (score 47):

The Hikari housekeeper runs every 30s, which closes any connections that are not in use and are older than `maxLifetime`. If there are more than `minimumIdle` number of connections, the housekeeper will close connections that have been idle for longer than `idleTimeout`.

If, while your app is running, there are no free connections, it will create another connection for you unless it's reached `maximumPoolSize` where you'll need to wait for one to be free.

Creating a new connection has an overhead. By pooling the connections, we save that connection time from happening everytime, so by reducing this down to 10s, you'll be adding a lot more overhead in comparison to every 10min.

For more info: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby