# Can too many Jdbc exceptions make the hikariCP overload and eventually timeout?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

An exception is thrown at `Jdbctemplate.update` *(unique key violation)*.

After certain number of these exceptions the hikaripool gets timed out with **connection not available** (Checked and found out that this error occurs due to pool overload)

Can too many sql exceptions cause a hikariCP timeout?

Comment: The short answer is, you have a *maximum number* of connection in the pool - if you try to open more connections, you get this error.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes that is the `hikariCP timeout` reason. My question is if a same sql error occurs too many times will this make too many unattended connections in the pool that puts **hikari** in a timeout

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber an oracle DB

Comment: If there are exceptions that return immediately and you close connection in code then there won't be any problem. If you have multiple exceptions due to long timeouts in db, it may cause reaching connection pool limit

Comment: @user7294900 Here have used spring-boot `JdbcTemplate` . therefor this will close the DB connection from spring container itself. But when using a connection pool the `connection` seems to be sent back to the pool itself.

Comment: you may need to define maxLifeTime, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924419/spring-boot-connection-pool-with-long-running-requests/52941224#52941224

Comment: @user7294900 `max-lifeTime:1800000` is already set in it with following hikari properties
`Connection-timeout / idle-timeout / maximum-pool-size / minimum-idle / max-lifetime `

Comment: This would suggest that your connection is not (or not promptly) returned to the pool, or that your connection pool is too small for your actual load.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Does after every `jdbctemplate` call will there be a `connection returned to the hicariCP (Even if an exception occurs on JDBC call) ?

Comment: I rarely use `JdbcTemplate`, and if I do it is in a `@Transactional` context. I'm not entirely familiar with how it handles connections.